# Statement if doesn't work

Tags: java

so I have being doing this program to verify if the word "bob" is in a string that the user enters. Example: "asddbobasd" -> "here is bob". Also, if there is one character between the bs it should print out "here is bob". Otherwise, it should print "here isn't bob".

tl dr: bxb = here is bob .bob = here is bob. bok = here isn't bob. When I'm executing the program, netbeans throws me an (!) at the if statement of (yed=='b' && zed=='b')

```
package lab;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Lab {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            char yed,zed;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            String x;
            System.out.println("Word");
            x = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            int m=0;
            for (int i = 0; i<=x.length(); i++) {
                yed = x.charAt(i);
                int j=i+2;
                zed = x.charAt(j);
                if (yed=='b' && zed=='b')
                    m++;
            }
            if (m>0){
                System.out.println("here is bob");
            } 
            if (m==0) {
                System.out.println("here isn't bob");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to seriously pick more meaningful variable names

Comment: Your for loop needs the break condition `i < x.length() - 2`, or you would get an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Also, in this program, if you input "bbb", it will report it as containing bob, even though it doesn't

Comment: And... `String.contains`, perhaps?

Comment: if you input "bbb" it should report that it contains bob, as long as a character is between the bs, is fine

Comment: The problem with string.contains is that it won't report that there is bob if there is a character between the bs.

Comment: OK, then `string.matches(".*b.b.*")`.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting Andy! Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i<=x.length(); i++) {
```

With using `i<x.length()-2` instead of `i<=x.length()`:

```
   for (int i = 0; i<x.length()-2; i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I don't understand why you subtract 2.

Comment: @Abdelhak I think that Rafael was asking why you suggest `x.length()-2`. You've not been downvoted twice.

Comment: I subtract 2 because you have this: int j=i+2; substracting 2 in this manner  j = -2 +2 =0 to start with j=0 index @RafaelMorazán

Comment: Ahhh.. I see, didn't think about it. Thanks again! I was struggling for such a fool mistake.